# Save selected option in dropdown menu in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert an image into a selected category in the drop down menu. Didn't want to hard code the menu in html so it can be dynamically updated by phpmyadmin to menu. Currently, all images insert in Greeting_Cards table because it is a place holder for now.

I have tried saving it as a variable: `$selected = $_POST['tables'];` and passing it as `$selected` rather than greeting_cards, but that throws back a notice of undefined index and doesn't add to any table at all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>upload</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
</form>


<?php
require_once('/var/db_file.php');

//To do after submit button
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 mysql_connect("localhost","root", $pass);
 mysql_select_db("images");

 $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
 $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

 /* Drop down menu */
 $dbname = "images";
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $tableNames=array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  $tableNames[] = $row[0];
 }

 echo '<select name="tables" id="tables">';
 foreach($tableNames as $name){
  echo '<option value="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';
 }
 echo '</select>';
 /* Drop down menu end */

    $selected = $_POST['tables'];

 echo '<br>';

 if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image"){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$selected` VALUES('','$imageName','$imageData')");
  echo "Image Uploaded!";
 }
 else{
  echo "Has to be an image!";
 }
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1: Added the $selected variable in, instead of Greeting_Cards**
**Fix: Moved ending tag of form to encompass the php code.**
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you var_dump the value of $row after assignation by mysql_fetch_row($result) ? Also try to spot the line number and actual code in which you are getting the undefined index error.

Comment: The undefined index notice is if I declare the variable: $selected = $_POST['tables']; And I don't know what var_dumping would do through your suggestion.

Comment: I dont see where in your code are you referring $_POST['tables'], is it in the db_file.php ? Either I see where In your form you are submitting a table input field so it gets included in the $_POST array.

Comment: I mean I removed it since it didn't work. But I edited it back in as if I would want to use it, Alariva. As I said before in the post, this throws back a notice of undefined index and doesn't add to any table at all.

Comment: You are now a step closer, seems you are missing to add the input field named tables in your for, or where do you want to get this value from?

Comment: The value from the selected drop down menu. The dropdown menu has the list of different categories (tables taken from the database).  I want to add the image to the specific category chosen from the drop down menu.

Comment: You are printing the select dropdown after you closed the form tag, that data is not being submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippet, the `$_POST['tables']` is not getting the assigned value, as the form does not have the select dropdown named **tables**.

Despite the dropdown is being echoed, it is outside the `<form>`, thus not being submitted.

Comment: Yup yup. I edited the closing tag of form and it is fixed.