# Retrieving foreign key value joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three database tables: hall, movie, and screening as shown below. 
[image: database tables]

In my screening table I have movie_id and hall_id as foreign key which references table movie and hall, respectively.

While adding the details of screening in my add detail form, I want to show a dropdown menu for available movie title and hall title from table hall and movie respectively.

But after I submit the form I want the ids of respective movies and halls but not their titles saved in the screening table.

How can I acheive this in PHP?

I have joined the three tables like this.

```
$sql="SELECT scr_id,scr_date,scr_start,scr_end,m.movie_id,h.hall_id 
        FROM screening as scr
        join movie as m on scr.movie_id=m.movie_id 
        join halls as h on scr.hall_id=h.hall_id";
```

And here is my add detail form:
[image: add detail form]

Here is the form which I am using to add the details. I have commented the first two elements as I am unable to derive the logic to add these elements.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['action'])&&$_GET['action']=="add")
    {

  ?>
<div class="cover">
<h1>Add Schedule</h1>

    <form action="scheduleact.php" method="post">
       <!-- <label for="title">Movie Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value=""/>
          <label for="hall">Hall</label><input type="text" name="hall" value=""/>  -->     
        <label for="date">Date</label><input type="date" name="date"/>
        <label for="start">Start Time</label><input type="time" name="start"/> 
        <label for="end">End Time</label><input type="time" name="end"/>                                             
        <p><input type="submit" name="addschedule" value="submit"/></p>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And this is scheduleact.php

```
function addschedule($date,$start,$end)
            {
                $sql="insert into screening (movie_id,hall_id,scr_date,scr_start,scr_end) values ('$movid','$hallid',$date','$start','$end')";
                $this->exeQuery($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            }
<?php
    include_once("../class/db_inc.php");

    if(isset($_POST['addschedule'])&&($_POST['addschedule']=='submit'))
    {
        //$movid=$_POST[''];
        //$hallid=$_POST[''];
        $date=$_POST['date'];
        $start=$_POST['start'];
        $end=$_POST['end'];
        $schedule->addschedule($date,$start,$end);
        echo "<script>alert('added successfully');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php?obj=viewschedule';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: within the HTML for populating the tables set the HTML value to the IDand the name component to name.  and return the ID, not the name to the php for insertion into the table.  for example:  `<select name="Movies">
  <option value="1">StarWars</option> </select>`  in PHP you refer to the value not the name/text  and if editing you add "Selected" text to the option value if that option is the one stored.

Comment: @xQbert I am new to this and so I am not quite getting you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: here's an example from a prior stack post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366802/save-selected-option-in-dropdown-menu-in-php  this line `echo '<option value="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';` would be changed to echo `<option value="' . $ID . '">' . $name . '</option>';` assuming ID was in the query.  This is step 1 so you have the values to save in the DB.  Then when you submit the form, the drop down selected value will contain the Id you need to store.  Your question is missing code we need to see. How is the page first populated to ensure the <option> has the correct value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think joining the tables together is not the approach you need to populate your dropdown menus. You can do two separate queries, one for movies and one for halls. Here is a general example. There are some missing pieces because I don't know what you are using to run your queries, but hopefully this can give you a general idea.

```
<select name="movie_id">
<?php
$movies_sql = 'SELECT movie_id, movie_title FROM movie';
//execute your query
while ($row = $query_result->fetch) {
    echo "<option value=\"$row[movie_id]\">$row[movie_title]</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="hall_id">
<?php
$halls_sql = 'SELECT hall_id, hall_title FROM halls';
//execute your query
while ($row = $query_result->fetch) {
    echo "<option value=\"$row[hall_id]\">$row[hall_title]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

You would mainly need to join the tables when you are retrieving screening records that you have already stored and you want to include the related information (movie and hall).

Comment: I executed this but I am getting an empty dropdown menu.

Comment: Yes, the code in my answer was not intended to be fully working code. You still need to connect to your database and execute the query. How you do that will depend on whether you are using mysqli, pdo, etc.

Comment: I have created a function for query execution
function exeQuery($sql){
  $res=mysql_query($sql);
  return $res;
  }
So I used     $res=mysql_query($halls_sql);
Still the dropdown menu is empty.

Comment: I connected to the database and did everything right. Now I am getting this error. 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails